# Unity application lens removed, no local apps now

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses

I was removing all of the Unity web result lenses, and somehow I've now got no local app results. This is what I did to remove them:

```
sudo apt-get purge unity-lens-music
sudo apt-get purge unity-lens-applications
sudo apt-get purge unity-lens-shopping
```

What should I do to get back my local apps without recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-applications
```

To restore *Applications Lens*

To turn off software recommendations, use [UnSettings](https://launchpad.net/unsettings)

[image: Unsettings]

Just turn off the "Apps for download" switcher.

[Unsettings download page](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/unsettings/#download).

Comment: Ok thanx I get that But will that in turn re-activate the software center reccomendations?

Comment: It will. See updated answer for instructions on how to disable them.

Comment: And where do I get this unsettings?

Comment: http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/unsettings/#download

Comment: Well in case it's not ___Obvious___ to some people,@Danatela I really appreciate your help.